# perl regex to extract a specifc word

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I have the following exmaple of a text file:

```
AFUA_2G08360|pyrG
AFUA_2G12630
gel1|bgt2|AFUA_2G01170
```

and I wish to do a regex to filter out `AFUA_2G08360`, `AFUA_2G12630`, `AFUA_2G01170` using `perl -l -ne` in unix command line.
How would you suggest to do that?

Comment: By "filter out", do you mean 1) print only tokens like AFUA_???????, or 2) print everything else?

Answer (score 1):

why not using 'sed' with something like

`sed 's/AFUA_2G\d{5}//'`

Answer (score 0):

```
AFUA_[0-9A-Za-z]{7}
```

See here : http://regexr.com?328gj

Command line :

```
user@mch:/tmp$ cat input.txt 
AFUA_2G08360|pyrG
AFUA_2G12630
gel1|bgt2|AFUA_2G01170

user@mch:/tmp$ cat input.txt | perl -lne "@matches = /AFUA_[0-9A-Za-z]{7}/g; print join("\n", @matches)";
AFUA_2G08360
AFUA_2G12630
AFUA_2G01170
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
/(AFUA_2G\d+)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a doable one-liner for your example input.

```
cat data | perl -l -e 'while (<>) {s/.*(AFUA_[^\|]*).*/\1/g; print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
perl -pe 's/.*(AFUA_[0-9a-zA-Z]*).*$/\1/' your_file
```

tested:

```
> cat temp
    AFUA_2G08360|pyrG
    AFUA_2G12630
    gel1|bgt2|AFUA_2G01170
> perl -pe 's/.*(AFUA_[0-9a-zA-Z]*).*$/\1/' temp
AFUA_2G08360
AFUA_2G12630
AFUA_2G01170
```